# Why bother prescribing oral antibiotics for acne, when C. acnes can't all be killed and will regrow?

Tags: antibiotics, acne

After topical antibiotics and/or retinoid and/or benzoyl peroxide, dermatologists commonly prescribe oral antibiotics, but why?

1. Presume that the patient dutifully consumes the [full prescribed course of antibiotics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/48724/4466).
2. Antibiotics may reduce the number of, but can't kill to the last drop *Cutibacterium acnes*.
3. Normally acne sufferers don't live in a sterile environment, and *C. acnes* may be floating in the air or lying on surfaces. Even if antibiotics kill every single bacterium of *C. acnes* this time, it'll probably colonize you again and regrow. *C. acnes* is

> largely [commensal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensalism) and part of the [skin flora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_flora) present on most healthy adult humans' skin.[[8]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutibacterium_acnes#cite_note-8) It is usually just barely detectable on the skin of healthy preadolescents. It lives, among other things, primarily on [fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid) in [sebum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebum) secreted by sebaceous glands in the [follicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_follicle). It may also be found throughout the [gastrointestinal tract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrointestinal_tract).[[9]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutibacterium_acnes#cite_note-expert-reviews2003-9)

3. Oral antibiotics mustn't be consumed forever.
4. After antibiotics kill most of the *C. acnes* and the patient stops taking the antibiotic, the remaining *C. acnes* (perhaps now resistant to that antibiotic) will proliferate to its formerly high concentration, and cause acne again.

My argument befits  the comments beneath.

[Subantimicrobial (low) Dose Doxycycline - antibiotics successful for moderate acne and rosacea without the resistant bacteria and changes to flora : scacjdiscussion](https://old.reddit.com/r/scacjdiscussion/comments/egfbjt/subantimicrobial_low_dose_doxycycline_antibiotics/)

> I took 50mg/daily for about two years and it worked a treat but when I stopped taking it the acne came straight back.

[[Acne] Stopping antibiotics after 2 and a half years : SkincareAddictionUK](https://old.reddit.com/r/SkincareAddictionUK/comments/6ccg0n/acne_stopping_antibiotics_after_2_and_a_half_years/)

> It's just once you've stopped taking the antibiotics, there's going to be a period of several weeks/going into months where your skin might be getting worse because you came off of the anitbiotics - or might be because of reactions to the new topicals.

Comment: Why the copy-paste of another user's question from another stack? While I don't think the question itself is "bad" I'm curious why not just push for the original to be migrated from Biology SE?

Answer (score 2):

Oral antibiotics (traditionally tetracyclines) have been found effective for treating acne for many years. Two major mechanisms inlcude:

1. inhibiting the growth of *C. acnes*
2. anti-inflammatory effect ([inhibits granuloma formation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8002645))

Of course, antibiotic resistance is a major concern, which is why oral antibiotics are generally prescribed for shortest duration possible (3-4 months) with [topical retinoids for maintenance therapy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26897386).

Resistance to tetracyclines was thought to be rare, but studies have begin finding [resistant strains](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28218057), so strong [antibiotic stewardship](https://www.cdc.gov/antibiotic-use/core-elements/index.html) will be vital for maintaining oral antibiotic efficacy.

Personal thoughts: Antibiotics most likely never completely eradicate a bacterial population, but by bringing down the bacterial load, you enable your immune system to maintain the remaining bacteria at a low enough level to avoid clinical symptoms.

Comment: Thanks. 5. Did you answer my point 3 "it'll probably colonize you again and regrow"? 6. Can you pls elaborate how "by bringing down the bacterial load, you enable your immune system to maintain the remaining bacteria at a low enough level to avoid clinical symptoms"? As Dr. Graham Chiu wrote  "Commensal bacteria on the skin are not controlled by the immune system" at https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/5605.